# Docbook: Enable icons for warning, caution and note items

Tags: warnings, docbook, xml-formatting

When using Apache XML-FO to output Docbook content to PDF, how can I achieve that the `<caution>`, `<warning>` and `<note>` elements are formatted with their icons instead of the plain title? I have enabled the `admon.graphics` parameter for the transformation, but this does not have any effect.

Comment: Did you also set `admon.graphics.path`?

Comment: That was the problem; if you add it as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must also set `admon.graphics.path`